# Обход DOM элементов в js

Tags: dom, javascript

Как **правильно** обойти все элементы DOM на странице (или во фрейме) и вывести их дерево с помощью js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать 2 свойства DOM элементов :

1. firstElementChild - первый потомок **текущего** элемента
2. nextElementSibling - следующий потомок **родительского** элемента

Вот пример реализации ( универсальный, для подобных структур ):

```
tab_buff = [];
function tab( level ){

  if ( tab_buff[level] ) return tab_buff[level];

  var i, res = [];

  for (i = 0; i < level; i++ ) res.push("|");
  res.push("-");

  return tab_buff[level] = res.join('');
}

function print_tree( root, child_prop, next_prop ){
  var stack = [],
      level = 0,
      curr = root,
      res = [],
      type = true;

  while( curr ){
    if ( type ) res.push( tab(level) + curr.tagName );

    if ( type && curr[child_prop] ){
      type = true;
      level++;
      stack.push( curr );
      curr = curr[child_prop];
    }
    else if ( curr[next_prop] ){
      type = true;
      curr = curr[next_prop];
    }
    else{
      type = false;
      level--;
      curr = stack.pop();
    }
  }

  return res.join("\n");
}

res = print_tree(
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
 'firstElementChild',
 'nextElementSibling'
);
```

в итоге в res будет что-то типа:

```
-HTML
|-HEAD
||-TITLE
||-STYLE
||-SCRIPT
||-SCRIPT
|-BODY
||-TABLE
|||-TBODY
||||-TR
|||||-TD
||||||-A
||||-TR
|||||-TD
||||||-FORM
|||||||-INPUT
|||||||-INPUT
|||||||-INPUT
||-SCRIPT
```

Comment: Надеялся на наличие унифицированного способа, функции. Но по видимому придётся-таки обходить через цикл.

Comment: Благодарю за рабочий пример

Answer (score 0):

Например вы хотите обойти все элементы с тегом "a", то есть все ссылки.
Тогда код будет иметь следующий вид:

```
var tag = 'a',//присваиваем переменной tag название нашего тега
    elems = document.getElementsByTagName(tag), //присваиваем переменной elems все элементы с название тега 'a'
    elem,//объявляем переменную elem, в ней будем хранить каждый элемент массива при его обходе
    k;//переменная k будет содержать порядковый номер элемента в массиве начиная с 0
for (k in elems) //для 
{
    elem=elems[k];
    //здесь может быть ваш код.
}
```

Напишите, что именно вам нужно, тогда я смогу ответить более конкретно.

Comment: 1. В вопросе написано что именно нужно.
2. Массив ( в т.ч. NodeList ) нельзя обходить функцией  for (k in elems)
3. Зачем копировать elems?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T1jeQXtA здесь код рекурсивной функции.
Пример использования getTree(document.body);